# Why do network taps have four ports?

Tags: tap, packet-analysis

I've been looking at a hardware network tap [like this one](http://www.netoptics.com/products/10100/10100baset-teeny-tap) to replace a pseudo-permanent SPAN that's been running on a Catalyst switch. All the taps I find have four interfaces: A, B, and two output ports (one for each direction). Ideally I would prefer to funnel the traffic from both directions into one cable so I only have to capture from one interface. Why do taps always seem to have two output ports?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Hardware network taps provide one output port in each direction to ensure that traffic can be replicated at line rate. For example, a 100 Mbps Ethernet connection provides a theoretical maximum of 200 Mbps of total bandwidth; 100 Mbps in each way. If you tried to capture traffic from a line which was carrying 75 Mbps in each direction, you would need at least 150 Mbps of one-way bandwidth: more than a single 100 Mbps connection can carry. Hence, taps include two output ports operating at the same speed as the line being monitored.

Answer (score 10):

Not all taps are "passive".  Look a few tabs down for ["aggregation" taps](http://www.netoptics.com/products/aggregation)

Yes, the most common quoted reason is to allow linerate monitoring, but the truth is far simpler... it takes pratically no logic to *individually* mirror the electrical signaling in each direction. (at least for 10/100, gig uses all four pairs) [I have various 10/100 passive taps.  Most of them have maybe $5 worth of logic in them. The good aggregation taps are tiny highspeed computers.]

Answer (score 8):

Like Jeremy said, you're only able to tap at line speed in one direction because normal connections are full duplex; you're only receiving. An added benefit/side effect/reason for doing so is to *ensure* that you don't put any packets back out on the wire (for passive taps).