# Cisco ASA: which side is "inside" with same security-level?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, acl, pix

I have an issue with an FWSM apparently killing RDP sessions after a random amount of time, and the log entry looks like:

```
Teardown TCP connection 145379776990678860 for MS_LZ1:10.30.3.150/49924 to LZ1_MS:10.254.0.217/3389 duration 0:01:58 bytes 705828 TCP Reset-I
```

I understand that "TCP Reset-I" means that a TCP Reset was received on the 'inside' interface, but in this particular firewall, both interfaces are security-level 0. Which one is the inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that "TCP Reset-I" means that a TCP Reset was received on the 'inside' interface, but in this particular firewall, both interfaces are security-level 0. Which one is the inside?

I have been looking at the PIX and FWSM docs for the last 30 minutes.  I could not find a source that clearly stated how the PIX / FWSM behaves in this situation.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to know with 100% certainty without a [packet capture](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/5147/775) to find the source of the reset.

FYI, [Cisco ASA flow-drop rules](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa71/command/reference/s2_711.html#wp1117924) say that `TCP Reset-I` is used for same-security traffic; since the FWSM and ASA are so close, I think it's a strong possibility that the syslogs simply don't give you enough information in this case.